# vertical Scrolling is not working for panel control in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, scrollbar, panel, desktop-application

In this only the downward scrolling is happening but I cannot scroll upward.

```
protected void BindData()
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    VScrollBar VScrollbar1 = new VScrollBar();
    this.vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    this.vScrollBar1.Height =  this.Height;
    this.vScrollBar1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(vScrollBar1_Scroll);
    panel.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
}

private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
      int value = (sender as VScrollBar).Value; 
      int hiddenPanelHeight = this.panel.Size.Height - this.Size.Height;
      float moveY = (float)hiddenPanelHeight * ((float)value / 100);
      int sValue = panel.Location.Y;
      int newY = (panel.Location.Y) - (int)moveY;
      this.panel.Location = new Point(this.panel.Location.X, newY);
}
```

Comment: Presumably you want to use NewValue/OldValue from the EventArgs to find out direction/distance for moving relatively to that. When you use value from the ScrollBar like here you would need to position absolutely. So the previous y position should be totally irrelevant then.

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)